# Using Jquery Tools can one center the Expose window?

Tags: jquery

I tried using position:relative with the width,height, and margin: 0 auto;

but it does not affect the overlay window.

I'm using the minimal setup for overlay http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html

It seems css wont affect how the expose/overlay window is aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery Tools plugin adds css code inline on the overlay element.  You can't override that style unless you specify !important in the style sheet.

Really, you should be controlling the overlay position through the given API documented here:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay.html

Check out the absolute property to see if that fixes your issue.  Give us some example code and we can help more!

Comment: but default the api aligns it "center" however that doesnt work for me because im adding this overlay in a Serena collage cms and it messes it up. 

Perhaps there is a more simpler jquery way to do it that allows me to use my own css?

Comment: Is it in an iframe?  If so, there is no way to center it relative to anything outside of the iframe.

Again, use !important to use your own CSS.

Post your specific code for more help.

Comment: Link in answer dead - 404 Not Found | Apologies! | We couldn't find what you're looking for..